# ionic g page home (replace page accidentally)

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm developing a Ionic 2 project and already had a page called "home", so I needed to create another page and did the command "ionic g page home", so my actual page "home" was replaced. There is any chance to get my "home" back? In atom editor don't have history and I can't restore in windows too.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered an issue as such once. I tried to get the file back using a recovery software. For my luck i got the file back. It might work for you as well. I used [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva). Try searching in the specified file location and you might recover the old version of the file. Not sure 100% that it would work, but it's worth a try.